# Diff between 2 timestamp - PHP

Tags: php, time, timestamp, diff

I am trying to calculate the difference between $timenow and $time.

```
$time = 2016-09-15 20:10:35
$timenow = 2016-09-15 20:40:42
```

I converted them to dateTime.

```
$time = new DateTime($time);
$timenow = new DateTime($timenow);
```

And then did the calculation:

```
$interval = $timenow->diff($time);
echo $interval;
```

Error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string

I looked at these
[difference between 2 timestamps in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815934/difference-between-2-timestamps-in-php)
and 
[Wrong hour difference between 2 timestamps (hh:mm:ss)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431308/wrong-hour-difference-between-2-timestamps-hhmmss)

Those didn't help.

Comment: `$interval` is an object, you need to format it. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php - As an example, `$interval->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: You probably want to use `format` on the object http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621270/php-object-of-class-dateinterval-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

Comment: Look http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract some date and time from current date and time to find age in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718155/subtract-some-date-and-time-from-current-date-and-time-to-find-age-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diff` is going to return a DateInterval object full of good information about the difference between your two dates.  You're just trying to echo that object which won't work.  Do a `var_dump()` to see the object's properties:

```
$time = "2016-09-15 20:10:35";
$timenow = "2016-09-15 20:40:42";

$time = new DateTime($time);
$timenow = new DateTime($timenow);

$interval = $timenow->diff($time);
var_dump($interval);
```

Then you can echo out the properties like:

```
echo $interval->i; // minutes
// 30
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php